# Alternatives to "Such As"

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, synonyms, clauses

> It will be more difficult for Bobby to behave well if Peggy is aggressive, such as hitting him or teasing him.

What is the right clause, expression or phrase to use instead of *such as*.  That doesn't seem to sound right.

Comment: Why don't you think it sounds right?

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-). The use of 'such as' [when giving an example of something](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/such) is standard and can be found in dictionaries. If you tried to find it with no success, please include your research in the question, so that it would be easier for others to understand what exactly is the source of confusion. This is a [good practice](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for all future questions you might have.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "such as" is too formal:

I might expect:

*"It will be more difficult for Bobby to behave well if Peggy **is aggressive, hitting and teasing him**."*

e.g.

> [Psychopathology of Childhood and Adolescence: A ...](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Shdx2IP5PrIC&pg=PA740&dq=%22aggressive,%20hitting%20and%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=odpCVasThd-wBOXIgaAG&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22aggressive%2C%20hitting%20and%22&f=false)  Page 740 Andrew
>   S. Davis - 2012
>
> He **was** frequently very **aggressive, hitting and kicking** other children
>   and often throwing temper tantrums.

or:

*"It will be more difficult for Bobby to behave well if Peggy **is aggressive, by hitting and teasing him**."*

> Your School-Age Child - Page 149 Lawrence Kutner - 1997
>
> In general, aggression in girls in our culture is different from
>   aggression in boys. Girls tend to be aggressive by excluding others
>   and by saying mean things. Boys are **aggressive by hitting and
>   getting into fights**.

Answer (score 0):

"It will be more difficult for Bobby to behave well if Peggy is aggressive, such as hitting him or teasing him."

Here are some alternatives:

"It will be more difficult for Bobby to behave well if Peggy **demonstrates** aggression, **by** hitting him or teasing him."

"It will be more difficult for Bobby to behave well if Peggy **continues to be** aggressive, **and also continues** hitting him or teasing him."

"It will be more difficult for Bobby to behave well if Peggy **doesn't resolve her** aggressive **behaviour**, **and remains** hitting him or teasing him."

Answer (score -1):

You could use *like* to replace *such as*.